# fetch data from html file in livecode

Tags: google-maps-api-3, livecode

i am using livecode and the google maps api to get 2 markers and the distance from markers.
the html file is on local specialfolder (ios-android).when the app is open the map show up **correctly**,on the html file exist a line that calculate the data `<body onload="calculateDistances(); ">`
but i want to fetch the data **(calculateDistances RESULTS)** from specific `<div id="outputDiv"></div>` without success.
when i put the bellow code i get nothing

```
put url theURL into tMap
```

or if i put the bellow code i get the file path

```
put url "url",theURL into tMap
```

here is a part of code in livecode

```
global myarray
Global browserID
Global theUrl
global tTitles
global thehtmlFile
global theData

on preopencard
   if the environment is not "mobile" then exit preopencard
     -- Create our browser control and store the id
          mobileControlCreate "browser"
    put the result into BrowserID
    mobileControlSet browserID, "rect", the rect of group "tbrowser"
    mobileControlSet browserID, "visible", "true"
    mobileControlSet BrowserID, "url", theURL
   set the text of fld "content" to theData


end preOpenCard

on closeCard
  put empty into fld "lat"  of card drecords
  put empty into fld "long" of card drecords

   if the environment is not "mobile" then
        exit closeCard
   end if
   -- Destroy the control, if we fail to do this native UIViews
   -- will just accumulate
        mobileControlDelete BrowserID
  delete URL("file:" & thehtmlFile) 

end closeCard
```

and here is the html code i am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <!--  <title>Distance Matrix service</title> -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&language=el&sensor=false"></script>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
             }
      #map-canvas {
    height: 99%;
    width: 100%;
      }
      #content-pane {
    width: 100%;
      }
      #outputDiv {
    font-size:smaller;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.078459, 23.734718);
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(38.078833, 23.736843);
var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|FF0000|000000';
var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=M|FFFF00|000000';
function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    center: origin1,
    zoom: 10,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), opts);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin1,],
      destinations: [destinationA,],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
    deleteOverlays();
    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        addMarker(destinations[j], true);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
        + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content-pane">
      <div id="inputs">
      </div>
  <body onload="calculateDistances(); ">  
      </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="outputDiv"></div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

i have update the code to show up how the file is loaded in specialfolder.

```
global myarray
Global browserID
Global theUrl
global tTitles
global thehtmlFile
global theData


on opencard
  dbArrayToCard myarray
      # quit if we are not on a mobile device
      if the environment is not "mobile" then exit opencard

    #Store Location 
  put fld"lat"& comma & fld"long" into Store_lng
  if fld"lat"or fld"long" is empty then
    //if store_lng is empty then
    answer error "No Gps Data"
    Answer "NOT able to track GPS location"
  end if
    
  #current location
  //wait 2000 millisecs
  put mobileCurrentLocation() into tLocation
  put tLocation["latitude"] into fld "Dlat" 
  put tLocation["longitude"] into fld "Dlong" 
  put fld"Dlat"& comma & fld"Dlong" into lat_lng


  if lat_lng is empty then
    answer error "NOT able to track GPS location"
  end if


  put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/navi2.html" into documentFilePath
       if there is not a file documentFilePath then
              put specialFolderPath("engine") & "/navi2.html" into engineFilePath
              put URL ("binfile:" & engineFilePath) into URL ("binfile:" & documentFilePath)
       end if

  put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/navi2.html" into thehtmlFile
          put URL("file:" & thehtmlFile) into theData
          
  put "var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(" & lat_lng & ");" into line 30 of theData
  put "var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(" & Store_lng & ");" into line 31 of theData
  put "zoom:17," into line 37 of theData

  put theData into URL ("file:" & thehtmlFile)
    put "file://" & specialFolderPath("documents") & "/navi2.html" into theURL
          replace space with "%20" in theURL

end OpenCard
```

Comment: Your LiveCode script doesn't contain any syntax that attempts to get data from an HTML file. Do you mean that you want to load a local file in the browser control?

Comment: One question on the side. Why don't you put spaces between `fld`and field names? E.g. `fld "Lat"`instead of `fld"Lat"`?

Comment: the code is temporary without format yet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that we're doing things the right way, I made a simple test script. Put the following script into the card script of a new stack. Save the stack with internal/external write permissions and internet permissions (just to make sure that we can access that; I don't even know if it is really necessary for this test).

```
global gBrowserID

on openCard
     put "<html><body>it works</body></html>" into myHtml
     put specialFolderpath("documents") & "/test.html" into myFile
     put myHtml into url ("binfile:" & myFile)
     put the result into rslt
     if rslt is not empty then
          beep
          answer rslt
     else
          put "file:///" & myFile into myUrl
          if there is a file myFile then
               mobileControlCreate "browser"
               put the result into gBrowserID
               mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"rect",the rect of this cd
               mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"visible",true
               mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"url",myUrl
          else
               beep
               answer "Can't find" && myFile
          end if
     end if
end openCard
```

Now install this on your Android device or run the stack in the emulator. It should display a browser with the words "it works". If it doesn't work, you should see an error message.

After testing this example, I stored your HTML code in a custom property and replaced the line `put myHtml into url ("binfile:" & myFile)`with `put the cMapHtml of this stack into url ("binfile:" & myFile)`. This seems to work. You can now replace parts of the HTML using

```
put the cMapHtml of this stack into myHtml
put "var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(" & lat_lng & ");" into line 30 of myHtml
put "var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(" & Store_lng & ");" into line 31 of myHtml
put "zoom:17," into line 37 of myHtml
put specialFolderpath("documents") & "/test.html" into myFile
put myHtml into url ("binfile:" & myFile)
// etc.
```

Just make sure that you really replace the correct lines. It is easy to make mistakes here.

---

Possibly, the file exists, but the URL is incorrect. Let's assume that your file path in the URL is of the form `/mnt/volume/directory/directory/file.html`. You may have to add `http:///`to create a valid URL that can be loaded in the browser.

```
on preopencard
   if the environment is not "mobile" then exit preopencard
   if there is a file theURL then
     repeat until char 1 to 3 of theURL is "///"
       put "/" before theURL
     end repeat
     put "http:" before theURL
     mobileControlCreate "browser"
     put the result into BrowserID
     mobileControlSet browserID, "rect", the rect of group "tbrowser"
     mobileControlSet browserID, "visible", "true"
     mobileControlSet BrowserID, "url", theURL
   else
     answer error "Can't find file"
   end if
   set the text of fld "content" to theData
end preOpenCard
```

This handler first checks that the file exist and then adjust the URL to make it a valid URL. If the file doesn't exist, it shows an error message.

Your updated code contains the lines

```
put "file://" & specialFolderPath("documents") & "/navi2.html" into theURL
replace space with "%20" in theURL
```

almost at the end.

Try using 3 slashes instead of 2. I'm not sure that you really need to replace the space with `%20`. Sometimes, this gets encoded into `%2520`. I would try again, both with and without replacing spaces.

```
put "file:///" & specialFolderPath("documents") & "/navi2.html" into theURL
replace space with "%20" in theURL
```

It seems that after these last lines, which put the URL into variable theURL, nothing else happens. There is no code to load the URL.

*Update:* Another other thing that might be of importance is the Application Permissions, which you can set in the Android pane of the Standalone Application settings. It might help to select `Write External Storage` and `Internet` if you haven't done so yet. There also the options `Fine Locations`and `Coarse Location`, which you might want to include as well.

---

I have saved your unmodified HTML code to a file and opened it on Firefox in Windows. That worked perfectly. I then did the same on my MacBook (Firefox, OSX 10.6.8) and that didn't work. When I try the same on my Android device, again it won't work. Apparently, this isn't a LiveCode problem but a google Mpas/Html problem.

Comment: hi Mark,thank you for your time..I get "Can't find file" on the simulator.I have **update** my code above how my file is loaded on the device(simulator)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please, try to update your code again.

Comment: i have test it,if i remove the line `replace space with "%20" in theURL` then i get empty map and i have replace the 2 slashes with 3,and still the same results :( i have include the photo that i get without change my code.the black letters on the bottom is the info i want to get from server [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/28k0cg5.png)

Comment: Really thx for your time to answer my questions Mark.The app both for android-ios have be checked many times gps,internet,wifi,storages and others is checked.the app exist at this moment on the Google play,just i want to make a fine upgrade of the app.Then only problem that we have stuck is ok we run the local file and we get the results to the browser,but how we get the data that coming from the google maps server?.if you want,just copy the html code and make html page,run it with double click and open development menu on safari or firefox and check the `<div id="outputDiv"></div>` info

Comment: I just noticed something! I have saved your unmodified HTML code to a file and opened it on Firefox in Windows. That worked perfectly. I then did the same on my MacBook (Firefox, OSX 10.6.8) and that didn't work. When I try the same on my Android device, again it won't work. Apparently, this isn't a LiveCode problem but a google Mpas/Html problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60552/discussion-between-user2602047-and-mark).